# How to search from a table using join?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, psql

So I have three tables as follows:

Members -> id, userId, accountId

Account -> id, name

User -> id, firstName, lastName, email

```
INSERT INTO `account` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
('1', 'xyz company'),
('2', 'abc company');

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `firstName`, `lastName`) VALUES
('1', 'abc@gmail.com', 'earth', 'flat'),
('2', '1@gmail.com', 'One hundred', 'pin'),
('3', '2@gmail.com', 'bull', 'horn'),
('4', '3@gmail.com', 'ball', 'yellow');

INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `userId`, `accountId`) VALUES
('1', '1', '1'),
('2', '1', '2'),
('3', '2', '1');

SELECT
  m.id,
  m.accountId,
  (
    SELECT
      JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'userId', u.id, 
        'firstName', u.firstName, 
        'lastName', u.lastName, 
        'email', u.email
      )
    FROM user
    WHERE user.id = m.userId
  ) AS user
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN members m ON m.userId = u.id
WHERE am.accountId = 1
GROUP BY m.id, u.id
```

The above sql gives me correct number of data as follows.

```
('accountId', 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName')
('1', 'abc@gmail.com', 'earth', 'flat')
('1', '1@gmail.com', 'One hundred', 'pin')
```

But when I do a search on the users from the same table, it gives me data also from `accountId` other than 1 when it should only give data from `accountId` 1.

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  m.accountId,
  (
    SELECT
      JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'userId', u.id, 
        'firstName', u.firstName, 
        'lastName', u.lastName, 
        'email', u.email
      )
    FROM user
    WHERE user.id = m.userId
  ) AS user
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN members m ON m.userId = u.id
WHERE am.accountId = 1,
OR LOWER(u.first_name) LIKE LOWER('%gma%')
OR LOWER(u.last_name) LIKE LOWER('%gma%')
OR LOWER(u.email) LIKE LOWER('%gma%')
GROUP BY m.id, u.id
```

This gives me all four data:

```
('accountId', 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName')
('1', 'abc@gmail.com', 'earth', 'flat'),
('2', 'abc@gmail.com', 'earth', 'flat'),
('1', '1@gmail.com', 'One hundred', 'pin')
```

The result should display only from `accountID` 1 but since there is matching in the name, its giving more result than expected.

The above query matches the `LIKE` with the user and returns members other than from `accountId` 1 which is true, but how can I write the query so that members are listed from `accountId` and also can be searched via name, email in users table.

Comment: Share some sample data. btw what does the function `json_build_object` does? And expected result set

Comment: What DBMS are you using -- `Postgres` or `MySQL`?  You have tagged `mysql` and `psql`.

Comment: @whatsinaname . . . I don't understand the rules you are using for searching.  If you only want to search on the account id, why are you doing comparisons on other fields?  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep in simple, something like this perhaps.

```
 SELECT 
  m.id, m.accountId,
  u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName,
  json_build_object('userId', u.id, 'firstName', u.firstName, 'lastName', u.lastName, 'email', u.email) as userobject,
  a.id as account_id,
  a.name as accountname


FROM
    users AS u
    LEFT JOIN members m ON m.userId = u.id  -- user and member

    LEFT JOIN  account as a  ON  a.id = m.accountId   -- connect to account from member

WHERE 
    (   
      u.firstName like '%gma%'
      0R 
        u.lastName  LIKE '%gma%'
       OR 
       u.email  LIKE '%gma%'
    )
 and   am.accountId = 1
```

Comment: the above query is giving me no result. The table is such that, there might be users without who are not part of members table, but I want to display only those users who are part of the member table and has accountId =1 and also be able to search the name, email etc

Comment: i modified my post, try to see if that works :) @whatsinaname
try to change the conditions whatever you wish.